# Angular components with no private methods

Tags: javascript, angular, private

I was talking with a coworker about private methods and he came to the conclusion that we should not use private methods inside an angular @Component since it is harder to unit test.

For me, is not a valid argument to not make it private so it will be easier to test. I think that private is to make it clear your intention about that method, that is used only in that class and is not called elsewhere. He said that, for angular components, its clear that you only going to use in that scope, in that page template. So the benefit of making clear (using private) is not as good as make it easier to test (using public).

I google for any recommendations about not using private methods in @Components but I couldn't find any.
So I was wondering if would be a good approach if all methods of a @Component are public (even if not needed to be) to make it easier to test?

Comment: You shouldn't make private methods public just so you can invoke them in tests - if they're private, that implies the *shouldn't* be tested directly, they're implementation detail. That said, many of the methods that *are* public (because all methods called from the template must be public)  also shouldn't be invoked directly in tests (e.g. event handlers, which you can trigger via the DOM). So short answer: no, that's not a valid argument.

Comment: Additionally, unit testing is generally the practice of making sure the given unit functions as designed. More specifically, it's supposed to validate the behavior of a given unit. If you have a component, testing the component is most effective when only the possible input/output/actions are taken on that component. How it functions internally is less of the concern. "Does my component accept this input?" "Does my form component emit this output with this value when this button is clicked and this form is filled out?" "Is this component showing this UI when it has this input?"